# groovy call for optional parameters

Tags: groovy

I have a method as follows:

```
void display(def a = null, def b = null) {

// user provides either value for a, or b
// if he gives value for a, it will be used 
// if he gives value for b, it will be used 

// not supposed to provide values for both a and b

}
```

My question is, how is user supposed to provide value for b?

If I use

```
display(b = 20)
```

It assigns 20 to `a`, which I don't want.

Is the only way to accomplish this is to call as follows?

```
display(null, 20)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Groovy method with optional parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18149102/groovy-method-with-optional-parameters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With optional parameters, yes you'd have to call `display(null, 20)`. But you can also define method to accept a `Map` instead.

```
void display(Map params) {
    if(params.a && params.b) throw new Exception("A helpful message goes here.")

    if(params.a) { // use a }
    else if(params.b) { // use b }
}
```

The method could then be called like this:

```
display(a: 'some value')
display(b: 'some other value')
display(a: 'some value', b: 'some other value') // This one throws an exception.
```

Comment: That was what I was looking for!! and makes perfect sense to the actual problem I was having in my project! Thanks a ton @Emmanuel Rosa!